# Proper locking system in a multithreaded sorting algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting, posix, mutex

Following problem:

My homework is expecting me to implement a multithreaded sorting system (I'm not asking you to do my homework, I have done most of it already and need help with a certain problem).

I have an array of N doubles which are filled with random numbers. For every index in this array there is a posix thread which is comparing its own index element with the element in the next index forever, until someone tells it to stop.

So, if we had the thread for index 5, it would forever compare itself to the next element and swap both if its own element is larger than the one in the next.

I have already implemented this whole system:

```
//related declarations
#define N 10

double x[N];
int isFinished = 0;
pthread_mutex_t indexMutex[N];

void* compareIndices(void* pindex)
{
    int index = *((int*)pindex);
    int nextIndex = index + 1;    

    if(nextIndex >= N)
    {
        nextIndex -= N;
    }    

    while(isFinished == 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&indexMutex[index]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&indexMutex[nextIndex]);
        if(x[index] > x[nextIndex])
        {
            double temp = x[index];
            x[index] = x[nextIndex];
            x[nextIndex] = temp;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&indexMutex[nextIndex]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&indexMutex[index]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    int indices[N];
    pthread_t tid[N];  

    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&indexMutex[i], NULL);
    }    

    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
    {
        indices[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, compareIndices, (void*)&indices[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think its needed to post my full code here, as this should already be enough to give you the idea. The system already works as intended, the array is perfectly sorted in the end.

However, I am not quite sure if my synchronisation is correct the way it is right now.

Currently, I have a mutex for every index to avoid typical multithreading problems, which could look like this:

Thread A fetches the values for x[index] and x[nextindex] and compares then, finding out x[nextIndex] is smaller, so it decides to swap. At this moment another thread B gets the CPU and moves another value in x[nextindex]. Back in Thread A the thread still thinks there is a mismatch and swaps yet again, but not with the original value from x[nextIndex], but rather with the value coming from the other thread.

Due to this I thought it might make sense to use a mutex for every index. However, after finishing this solution I remembered the philosoph problem:

What would happen if all threads fetch their x[index] lock at the same time, and all at once would try to fetch x[nextIndex] next? It most likely would end up in an unsolvable deadlock, as all mutexes are already locked, and no thread would  be able to continue.

I never had this happening in all my tests, but the possibility is there. However, I am not quite sure what other options I do have to make this safe.

Is there any word of advice to guide me to a proper solution?

Comment: Yes, your threads-philosophers can suffer from both a deadlock and a livelock. Some solutions are outlined in the [wikipedia page for the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Solutions).

Comment: Note that you don't wait for the threads. So, `main` exit will exit the entire process. You either need to use `pthread_join()` on threads or just `pthread_exit()` from main.

Comment: @usr Oh, right, I cut that out of the sample code, shouldve had it kept in there

Comment: What happens if all threads lock their own index, and then go to lock the nextIndex? deadlock i think. Easy solution whould be to pick one thread at random and make it pick the locks in different order. i.e lock firstIndex and then index.

Comment: Having to take two locks on every comparison is going to kill your performance. You might reconsider your approach so you don't have to use any locks at all. Consider something a divide-and-conquer algorithm like a parallel quicksort or parallel merge sort.